# error displaying customer in desc order limit 5

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

**controller**

```
        $this->load->model('Customer_model');
        $users = $this->Customer_model->recently_registered();
        $this->load->view('dashboard', $users);
```

displaying customer in desc order limit 5
**model**

```
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('customer');
        $this->db->order_by('date_added', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit(5);
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

**Output blank**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPrnq.png)

Comment: What error are you getting in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```html
        $this->load->model('Customer_model');
        
        //fetch data like this
        $users['customer'] = $this->Customer_model->recently_registered();
        $this->load->view('dashboard', $users);
```

You didn't show how you are displaying the data into the table but basically you will have to use customer variable data you passed as follows:

```html
foreach ($customer as $customers){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$customers->columnvalue."</td>";


echo "<td>" . $customers->columnvalue...n . "</td>";


echo "</tr>"


}
```